# How to define "executable" solver path with pyomo multistart

Tags: python, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt, non-convex

I am having a non-linear minimization problem apparently with non-convexity. I use the Pyomo framework for an energy system operation optimization model, where a once configured optimization model needs to be evaluated in sequential hours (I create the optimization problem at the beginning, defining the variables, constraints and objective function for the specific system and then I try to solve this created set up for the "simulation " time frame (e.g. for every hour in a given year), changing only the energy demand parameter, ...minimizing operation costs). I have noticed that for some random hours an optimum cannot be found. In most of these failed cases I get "max iteration number reached", sometimes "restoration failed" result.
To overcome this problem I would like to use the Pyomo "multistart" method (`pyo.Solverfactory('multistart').solve(model)`), which by default uses the IPOPT solver. I had been using it previously as well, but then I had the syntax:
`pyo.Solverfactory('ipopt', executable=...ipopt.exe)`
In this new case with multistart though I cannot define the executable for the IPOPT solver. Could you please help me how to solve this problem?(...or suggest alternatives to multistart to overcome the starting point issue of non-convex minimization)
So far I have tried:
`pyo.Solverfactory('multistart', executable=...ipopt.exe).solve(model)`
`pyo.Solverfactory('multistart').solve(model, solver='ipopt', executable=...ipopt.exe)`
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There should be an argument to pass in a dictionary of keyword arguments to the solver. See solver_args (https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contributed_packages/multistart.html#using-multistart-solver)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30645781)